# R PortfolioAnalytics

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory

I am not able to find PortfolioAnalytics package for windows from CRAN. New to R, will greatly appreciate any help how to find and install this package.

Comment: temporarily (?) archived, you can find an old version here: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/PortfolioAnalytics/ . Just download it, then `R CMD INSTALL PortfolioAnalytics*.tar.gz`

Comment: Thanks! I am totally novice in this area, when I run this I got "make" not found ... compilation failed.. I am running this on windows10. So I need to install "make"? what is the best source to install 'make'. Sorry to ask trivial questions!

Answer (score 1):

Download the zip file from https://github.com/braverock/PortfolioAnalytics
Extract the files
Then goto your CMD line.
Goto the folder containing PortfolioAnalytics
Type "R CMD build PortfolioAnalytics"
Once its complete, it will display a message with the file name
Type "R CMD INSTALL *file-name*

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Totally novice in this area, I got the following error when running build: "cannot open file 'man": no such file or directory

Comment: We have all be there! I was getting errors when I tried to do that way too. Try this method, it worked for me:
1. install.packages("devtools")
2. devtools::install_github("braverock/PortfolioAnalytics")

Comment: Thanks again! I installed "devtools", but on step 2, I got:from URL https://api.github.com/repos/braverock/PortfolioAnalytics/zipball/master
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 3.5.0 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.5). I installed an earlier version of devtools, but still getting similar messages. Any idea?

Comment: Is it an error or just warning?

Comment: It is an error and the package was not installed.

Comment: Did you install Rtools?